# Create Vue.js object on existing data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following code generated by my server :

```
<div id="app-4" data-server-rendered="true">
  <ul>
    <li>Article 1 test1</li>
    <li>Article 2 test2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now with Vue.js, I would like to generate again this code if data changes. Is that possible ?

I tried to do something but it doesn't work :

```
var app4 = new Vue({
  el: '#app-4',
  props: ["todo"],
  template: '  <ul>\n' +
  '    <li v-for="todo in todos">\n' +
  '      {{ todo.title }} {{ todo.text }}' +
  '    </li>\n' +
  '  </ul>',
  data: {
    todos: [
      { title: 'Article 3', text:"test1" },
      { title: 'Article 4', text:"test2" },
      { title: 'Article 5', text:"test3" }
    ]
  }
})
```

Theoritically, as I put a data.todos value which is not the same than in output generated by the server, it should change. But it stays with my 2 li. If I remove data-server-rendered="true", it will display my 3 li.

Comment: Get rid of `props` on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was due to \n

My html has to be like this

```
<ul id="app-5" data-server-rendered="true"><li>Learn JavaScript test1</li><li>Learn Vue test2</li><li>Build something awesome test3</li></ul>
```

And my js :

```
var app5 = new Vue({
 el: '#app-5',
 template: '<ul id="app-5"><li v-for="todo in todos">{{ todo.title }} {{   todo.text }}</li></ul>',
 data: {
  todos: [
   { title: 'Learn JavaScript', text:"test1" },
   { title: 'Learn Vue', text:"test2" },
   { title: 'Build something awesome', text:"test3" },
  ]
 }
})
```

I guess it would have worked without problem if I would have used a template for both rendering. This is what I will do.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are trying to have Vue overwrite the tag that includes the `data-server-rendered`. You want to put your hydration inside that. If I set `el: '#app-4'` (as you do), I get an error:

> The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching
>   server-rendered content.

If I set `id="app-5"` in the `ul` and use `el: '#app-5'` in my Vue spec, I don't get that error, and everything renders ok.

```js
var app4 = new Vue({
  el: '#app-5',
  template: '  <ul>\n' +
  '    <li v-for="todo in todos">\n' +
  '      {{ todo.title }} {{ todo.text }}' +
  '    </li>\n' +
  '  </ul>',
  data: {
    todos: [
      { title: 'Article 3', text:"test1" },
      { title: 'Article 4', text:"test2" },
      { title: 'Article 5', text:"test3" }
    ]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app-4" data-server-rendered="true">
  <ul id="app-5">
    <li>Article 1 test1</li>
    <li>Article 2 test2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is now that if I don't set todos array, there will be an error saying that todos is undefined. I have the felling it always wants to re-create datas even if I need to keep Article 1 and Article 2

Comment: Yes, it is going to overwrite anything in there. Your todos should include everything you want to display. If Article 1 isn't in your todos data, it doesn't belong in the list. Otherwise, you're saying that server-rendered data is permanent.

Comment: All right. What I need to do is that server renders my list, then when I click on a button, data changes (i know how to do this, it's not a problem). As I understand, when my page loads, I need to set my todos with the exact same values than the html list already contains. But will Vue.js overwrite even if data is the same ? In such case, it's not really optimal.

Comment: If it overwrites but the data is the same, is it really overwriting?

Comment: You may want to ask a new question so you can describe in more detail the behavior you're trying to get.

Comment: Yes it is overwriting because JS is doing an useless action. It displays something which has already been displayed. Maybe I will create a new question but I'm not sure solution exists.

Comment: Vue only changes things that need changed. It doesn't rewrite things that are already as they should be. https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/02/21/vue-js-virtual-dom/

Answer (score 0):

on your js page can you declare the template using components.

```
Vue.component('todo',{
    template:`<ul><slot></slot></ul>`,
});
```

and on your html page

```
<todo>
<li v-for="todo in todos">{{todo.title}}</li> 
</todo>
```

Comment: I don't really understand why I should add this on my html page. When I do it, something not very beautiful appears : {{todo.title}}
and my data is not updated.